# Automatic web tester for 404 links?

Tags: web-testing

Is there any test framework or software that can automatically go through a site and find 404 errors from links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an extension for your favourite browser, i.e. [LinkChecker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/532/) for Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a tool that does complete validation/checking of the site? Or one that does use-case testing of specific parts of the site.

For the latter I recommend [TestPlan](http://web.archive.org/web/20100819120725/http://testplan.brainbrain.net/), it has the ability to check the headers of pages and work with the so-called "meta" response of the page.
The original web-site is no longer available but the project is now [hosted on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/testplan).

For the former it isn't the best tool, but as part of a test framework it is easy enough to get it to scan through links on the site looking for errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Windows there is this [one](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html).